# Using mkdocs failed loading extension pymdownx despite it being installed

Tags: pip, ubuntu-18.04, mkdocs

I tried using [mkdocs-material](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/) for hosting an existing project repository i made changes on locally to see if everything is display the right way. But when trying to use the command `mkdocs serve` I get an error

```
ERROR   -  Config value: 'markdown_extensions'. Error: Failed loading extension "pymdownx.tabbed".`
```

caused by the given configuration of the project in its mkdocs.yml file.

So i made sure to install the requested [PyMdown Extensions](https://pypi.org/project/pymdown-extensions/). Despite that I still get the same error. I dont know why it fails to load the PyMdown extension. I even checked my `dist-packages` folder and `pymdownx` was listed as expected.

Does anyone have an idea, what may cause this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install pymdown-extensions --force
```

And then:

```
mkdocs build --clean
```

Worked for me.

Comment: I hit the same error and this didn't help for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error and I didn't manage to find the root cause. I found that upgrading to **Python 3.9** resolved this for me. I was experiencing the error on Python 3.5.

Updating pymdown and force installing didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I updated mkdocs and that worked for me. The issue was that a previous version of mkdocs only accepted certain versions of markdown and I had the newest version of markdown. Updating mkdocs allowed the newest version of markdown.